# Object don't update after Api Call on SwiftUI

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui, environment

Im trying to do a simple SwiftUI App to fetch recent movies premiers

Trying to follow MVVM and found a couple of tutorials to make the Api calls but they put the Api calls on the model

So i so try to make a Service class And a State class to handle my @Observed objects the problem is when I try to see the movie details the details don't load, but when I try another movie the details are of the last movie

[You can see the bug here](https://twitter.com/misaellandero/status/1316852576864923648?s=21)

This is my Movies Service

```
public class MoviesService {
    
    private let apiKey = "?api_key=" + "xxx"
    private let baseAPIURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"
    private let language = "&language=" + "es-MX"
    
    var nextPageToLoad =  1
    
    var nowPlayingMovies = [Movie]()
    var movieDetail : MovieDetail?
    
    
    init() {
        loadNowPlaying()
    }
        
    func loadNowPlaying(){
  
        let urlString = "\(baseAPIURL)now_playing\(apiKey)\(language)&page=\(nextPageToLoad)"
        print(urlString)
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:parseMovies(data:response:error:))
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func parseMovies(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?){
            var NowPlayingMoviesResult = [Movie]()
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(NowPlaying.self, from: data) {
                    // we have good data – go back to the main thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                        // update our UI
                      
                        NowPlayingMoviesResult = decodedResponse.results!
                        self.nextPageToLoad += 1
                        
                        for movie in NowPlayingMoviesResult {
                            nowPlayingMovies.append(movie)
                        }
                    }
                    // everything is good, so we can exit
                    return
                }
            }
            
            // if we're still here it means there was a problem
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        
    }
    
    func loadDetailMovie(id : Int) {
        
        let urlString = String("\(baseAPIURL)\(id)\(apiKey)\(language)")
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:parseDetailMovie(data:response:error:))
        task.resume()
         
    }
    
    func parseDetailMovie(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?){
            
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(moviesApp.MovieDetail.self, from: data) {
                    // we have good data – go back to the main thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.movieDetail  = decodedResponse
                    }
                    // everything is good, so we can exit
                    return
                }
            }
            
            // if we're still here it means there was a problem
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        
    }
 }
```

This is my State class

```
class StateController: ObservableObject, RandomAccessCollection {
    
    typealias Element = Movie
    
    @Published var movies = [Movie]()
    
    @Published var movie : MovieDetail?
    
    private let moviesService = MoviesService()
    
  
    func shouldLoadMoreData(item : Movie? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        if item == movies.last {
           return true
        }
        return false
    }
    
    func reloadMovies(item : Movie? = nil){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.shouldLoadMoreData(item: item) {
                self.moviesService.loadNowPlaying()
            }
            self.movies = self.moviesService.nowPlayingMovies
        }
    }
    
    
    func loadMovieDetails(id: Int){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.moviesService.loadDetailMovie(id: id)
            self.movie = self.moviesService.movieDetail
        }
    }
    
    var startIndex: Int { movies.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Int { movies.endIndex }
    
    
    subscript(position: Int ) -> Movie {
        return movies[position]
    }
    
}
```

And this is My Movie Detail View

```
import SwiftUI

struct MovieDetailView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var stateController: StateController
    @State var id : Int
 
    var body: some View {
        DetailMovieContent(movie: $stateController.movie)
            .onAppear{
                stateController.loadMovieDetails(id: id)
            }
    }
}
```

So this is my questions

Im doing a good Approach?
Whats the right way of make and Api call using MVVM and SwiftUI?

[The full App is here](https://github.com/misaellandero/MovieMVVM/tree/main/moviesApp)

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Comment: Thank you, just was a key for an api but not a big deal.